# Unity. Creating a inspector slider with custom values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider, inspector

How would I create a slider in Unity Inspector that slides between following values: {3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15}?

I can only find how to do a slider using range but as you can see I want my values to be odd between 3 and 15.

Tried doing this, but does not work:

```
[{3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15}]
public int mySliderOdd;
```

I am using C#.

Comment: You can do this with an Editor script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check "Whole numbers" on slider in editor and then write this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SliderScript : MonoBehaviour {

    float prevVal;
    Slider slider;

    void Start(){

        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
        prevVal = slider.value;

        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener (delegate {ValueChangeCheck ();});

    }

    void ValueChangeCheck()
    {

       if (slider.value % 2 == 0) {   //check odd value

            slider.value = prevVal;

        } else {

            prevVal = slider.value;

        }

    }
}
```